# Inputs needed on Restoring Categories in Sitecore Order Cloud

Tags: sitecore-commerce, ordercloud

Issue:
We ran into an issue where the Sub Categories of the Category has been deleted in Sitecore Order Cloud due to which the Sub Categories and the Related products are not showing up on the Website.
Need inputs like is there is any way to restore the categories to a particular data so that we get the Sub Categories along with category.
Posting it as it needs an immediate fix.
Any Suggestions are Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to recover accidentally deleted data, categories or otherwise, on OrderCloud.

Source: I'm a lead developer of OrderCloud

Comment: Kindly share some more details to your answer.

Comment: I'm a lead developer of OrderCloud, and there is no way to restore accidentally deleted data.